# Algorithms timely to compute but quick to validate computed results

Tags: algorithm

I want to give a user a random key, ask him to perform an algorithm on this key. Algorithm has to be costly to compute. There should exist no *known* workaround to cut the computation time needed. And I should be able to validate in non costly way that computed value was indeed computed from the key I gave.

Are there any algorithms suitable for this kind of purpose?

Comment: I think you are describing *public-key cryptography* in which factorisation of large integers plays the role of the algorithm to which you refer.  I suggest recourse to your favourite search engine.

Comment: Take two big primes. Multiply them. Give the user the result and let him find the two prime factors.

Comment: You are looking for an NP-hard problem.  Very roughly, those are hard to solve but easy to verify.  (Most require more than just a random key as input but you could use that key to say, seed a random number generator that is used to generate a graph and solve an NP-hard graph problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh yes there are. Bitcoin for example uses such a thing, it's called a [Proof-of-work system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work), also look at [Hashcash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcash).

Sorry I can't help you with the actual code for it, but there should be plenty of open source material available.
For bitcoin, from what I understand, there is a (very small) chance to finish this proof of work quickly, but on average it's very hard. Using a normal computer it will take more than just a few decades.

Answer (score 1):

Cryptography comes to mind here.  Take a data set A, encrypt it using key K, with the result being B.  Give the user A and B, ask him to recover K.  Of course you have to pick key size and algorithm in a way that makes this task practical. 
Or take a short, random string, like 10 or 20 characters.  Calculate the SHA1-hash.  Give the user the hash, and ask him to recover the original string.
Or factorization.  Give the user the product of two large primes, and ask him to recover the factors.